# Nearest Square Function with Python

Tags: python

I have this sample quiz question but not to sure how to approach it with while loops.

Implement the nearest_square function. The function takes an integer argument limit, and returns the largest square number that is less than limit.

A square number is the product of an integer multiplied by itself, for example `36` is a square number because it equals `6*6`.

There's more than one way to write this code, but I suggest you use a while loop!

Here is a test case you can copy to test your code. Feel free to write additional tests too!

```
test1 = nearest_square(40)
print("expected result: 36, actual result: {}".format(test1))
```

I have managed to solve it. Thank you.

```
def nearest_square(limit):
    limit = limit ** (0.5)
    y = int (limit)
    while y < limit :
         y = y*y
    return y

test1 = nearest_square(40)
print("expected result: 36,actual result:{}".format(test1))
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: You don't need a `while` loop for this.

Comment: The quiz requirement was to use a while loop.

Comment: "I don't know how to do this with a while loop" doesn't change the fact that you're looking for an entire solution from scratch without showing any effort. Have you made any progress with _any_ approach?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following method to return the nearest square given the `limit` parameter:

```
def nearest_square(limit):
    answer = 0
    while (answer+1)**2 < limit:
        answer += 1
    return answer**2
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `answer=0`? I assigned `answer to 1` and it gave me the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it's more efficient to approach this kind of questions mathematically (maybe not for low inputs but certainly yes for pretty big numbers). That said, we have a good tool at hand: the `square root`.

If computing the square root of any number, n, yields a `double` value whose decimal part is fully composed by zeroes then your number is a perfect square (square of an integer).

Interestingly (and this is more related to your question), `if you choose another number` (that is not a perfect square) `and apply a rounding operation` (floor or ceil) `you'll get the closest square` (lower or bigger).

An example:

```py
n = 24
sqrt = math.sqrt(n) # sqrt(24) = 4.898979485566356...
closest = [math.floor(sqrt)**2, math.ceil(sqrt)**2] # closest = [16, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it with while loop:

```
def nearest_square(value):
    i = 2
    while i < value:
        square = i*i
        if square == value:
            return square
        i+=1
        value-=1

print (nearest_square(40))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def nearest_square(value):

  i = 1
  result = 1
  while (result < value):

   if (result == value):
      return result
   i+=1
   result = i*i

  return (i-1)*(i-1)
```

print (nearest_square(82))

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code:

`

```
def nearest_square(limit):
    while limit > 3:
        i = 2
        while i <= limit//2:
            square = i*i
            if square == limit:
                return square
            else:
                i += 1
        limit -= 1
    return 1
```

`

Comment: Consider a small explaination

Answer (score -1):

Here's what i did.

```
def nearest_square(limit):
    y = 0
    while y**2 < limit:
        y+=1
    if y**2 == limit:
        return(y)
    return(y-1)

print(nearest_square(40))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation of it.

this one is with while loop

```
def near1(limit):
    i = 1
    square = 1
    while (i*i) < limit:
        square = i*i
        i = i+1
    return square
```

but the easiest one is below. 
Simple math and modulo

```
import math
def near(limit):
    i = int(math.pow(limit, .5))
    return i*i
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what i did.

```
import math  
def nearest_square(limit):
    a = math.sqrt(limit) 
    while type(a) != type(int()):
        limit -=1
    return limit
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't even run. Aside from this it's an endless loop. I you don't seem to understand how python casts numeric types.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm also relatively new to python so maybe I don't understand how python casts numeric types. I think the problem was with my indentation which I've corrected. I'm doing the same quiz, that was my solution and it ran.

Comment: As you can see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_sqrt.htm sqrt will always return a float as a return, even if the input is an integer spare. That's how you get the infinite loop. You'll need a different test.