# Nearest Square Function with Python - why is my solution is incorrect

Tags: python, while-loop, square

I was told to post a new question - refer to post : [Nearest Square Function with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762619/nearest-square-function-with-python)

objective is as find largest nearest square to limit = 40.

I came up with a solution but I didn't understand why this doesn't work. Correct outcome would be printing the numbers up to 36, not exceeding 40.

```
limit = 40 #given limit by quiz 
num=0 #set point by me 
square=num*num #this is what a square means #it could also be said of num**2 

while square<limit:
    square=num**2
    num=num+1
    print((num-1),square)
```

result i would get is :

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
```

**why does the line 7 square 49 appear ?**

Comment: In each iteration of the loop, you generate the next square - and unconditionally print it.  Only after that do you check if it's over your limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is beacause you are checking `square < limit` and when the `number = 6` the  `suare = 25` which satisfies the condition and the line `6 36` is printed next the number turns `7` andsqure turns `36` which is still less then 40 therefore it prints `7 49` and increments the number to `8` and now when the program checks for the `while condition` it fails as `49 < 40 == False` therefore the program execution stops.
you could modify your code as:

```py
    limit = 40    # given limit by quiz 
    num = 1    # start with 1 as 0 suare is 0 and is not required by you i guess
    while (num * num) < limit:
        print((num),(num * num))    # prints num and square of num
        num += 1        # increments num by 1
```

Output:

```py
    1 1
    2 4
    3 9
    4 16
    5 25
    6 36
```

Comment: thank you for the share! I modified my code by yr suggestion with num+=1 placed at the last line and now it works 

limit = 40
num=0 
# write your while loop here
while num**2<40:
    nearest_square = num**2
    print(num,nearest_square)
    num=num+1

Comment: Welcome dear..! Wish you a happy coding journey..!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the Python interpreter will execute everything inside the loop and only break once the condition square < limit is evaluated as false.

In this final iteration of the loop num = 8 and square = 49. The loop then correctly evaluates 49 < 40 as false and breaks. It will not break inside the loop as soon as the condition becomes false, only when the "square < limit" is evaluated.

A potential solution could be placing the print inside an if statement like so,

```
if square < limit:
     print stuff
```